# "Vagrant Up" error

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I entered "vagrant up" in the terminal and got this:

```
/opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb:31: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/sbin in PATH, mode 040777
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning:                 Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/sbin in PATH, mode 040777
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
```

I tried doing it with the VirtualBox GUI open and got the same thing.

Also if I try to start it in the GUI I get this:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine FlarumVm.

Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks! (BTW I have virtualization enabled in the bios.

Comment: Experiencing the same on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.. It seems this was a problem that occured in some early Mac Users in 2013 https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1671 .. So now it seems like a bug occuring to Ubuntu users as well

Comment: You might consider using [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) instead of VirtualBox and [libvirt provider](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt). KVM is way more efficient than VirtualBox. You should update Vagrant as well. You are running version 1.7.1 while the current version is 1.8.1.